# How to use a setuid bit on a Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuid

I want to check if the setuid bit is correct for my Python script, so I'm trying to add some code to print the user that's running it.

I tried  `getpass.getuser()` but I believe that looks at environment variables to determine the user. I don't think a setuid bit is altering environment variables.

I also tried `os.geteuid()` but that prints out a number and I'm not sure how to correlate that to a username.

Is there any other way to check the effective user of a Python script?

Comment: I think it is not possible to use suid on scripts: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts#2910

Comment: @HeapUnderflow That's what I'm starting to think too. Since my code is a cgi script, I'm looking into using Apache's suEXEC to run it as a certain user.